# Reading and Writing JSON through Python

Tags: python, json

read.json file :

```
{
    "Username" : "admin",
    "Password" : "admin",
    "Iterations" : 5,
    "Decimal" : 5.5,
    "tags" : ["hello", "bye"],
    "Value" : 5
}
```

program.py File:

```
import json 
with open('read.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

data = str(data)
data.replace("'",'""',10)
f = open("write.json", "w")
f.write(data)
```

write.json file :

```
{'Username': 'admin', 'Password': 'admin', 'Iterations': 5, 'Decimal': 5.5, 'tags': ["hello", "bye"], 'Value': 5}
```

What I want to achieve :

1. Read JSON data from read.json File
2. Parse and modify some values from the JSON in my program
3. Write to another write.json file (In JSON Format)

There are no errors in my code, but the write.json does not contain the values in double quotes(""), it rather as the values wrapped in single quotes making it not a proper JSON format.

**What change needs to be done to make the write.json file to contain proper JSON format and also 'pretty-write' to write.json file.**

Comment: You should modify the `data` (which will be a `dict`) as you receive it from the `json.load()` call and write it back to a file using `json.dump()`. No need to use `str()` inbetween.

Comment: you json looks fine ( I check it from my side ) , just change `json.load(data)` to `json.loads(data)`

Comment: @quamrana you are correct `loads()` takes str not file `.json`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can directly dump json data to file. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage)

```
import json
with open('read.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    # sort_keys, indent are optional and used for pretty-write
```

To read json from file:

```
with open('read.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you're converting your dictionary to string using python  representation which prefers simple quotes.

As Vikash answer states, no need to convert to string (you're losing the structure). Change your data, then let `json.dump` handle the dict to text procedure, this time respecting json format, and using double quotes.

Your question was mentionning "prettying" the output, you can achieve this by adding extra params to `json.dump`

```
data["Username"] = "newuser"  # change data

with open("write.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data,f,indent=4,sort_keys=True)
```

now file contents is:

```
{
    "Decimal": 5.5,
    "Iterations": 5,
    "Password": "admin",
    "Username": "newuser",
    "Value": 5,
    "tags": [
        "hello",
        "bye"
    ]
}
```

- `indent`: choose indentation level. Has the nice effect of "prettying" the output
- `sort_keys`: if set, the keys are sorted alphabetically, which guarantees the same output every time (python key order is random)