# Don't really know how to work with json files

Tags: python, json

I have a little problem. I don't know much about json and I need help. I have main.py file and the .json file. I, for example, want to output a certain line from .json file in print() in main.py. For Example, the json file has the line `"name":"Alex"` and the second line `"name":"John"`. I need to make sure that it finds the line `"name":" Alex"` in the json file and outputs the name Alex in main.py. I hope I have made my question clear

So this is a piece of json file. It's Schedule of university

```
"group": "КМБО-02-19",
      "days": [
        {
          "day": "ПН",
          "pars": [
            {
              "name": "Введение в ПД",
              "type": "зачет",
              "number": 3,
              "place": "Б-209",
              "whiteWeek": 17
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "day": "ВТ",
          "pars": [
            {
              "name": "Программирование в ЗР",
              "number": 2,
              "place": "Б-209",
              "type": "зачет",
              "whiteWeek": 17
            },
            {
              "name": "Физкультура и спорт",
              "type": "зачет",
              "number": 5,
              "whiteWeek": 17
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: Why the name Alex? What is the overall structure of the JSON file?

Comment: A JSON file is not about single lines. It defines a whole datastructure. Read the file with the `json` module and then access the values you want. How to do that depends on the type of the structure. It might be a single list, but it could be something like a list in a dictionary in a dictionary in a list.

Comment: [json is a documented format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and [there's a json package in the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to unserialize json strings to Python objects. Once you have unserialzed your json to Python, it's just plain python dicts and lists stuff.

Comment: Your json snippet is not valid json.

Answer (score 0):

An example tailored exactly to OPs question edit:

```
import json

# read the json
# with open('data.txt') as f:
    # json_data = json.load(f)

json_data = {
    "group": "КМБО-02-19",
    "days": [
    {
      "day": "ПН",
      "pars": [
        {
          "name": "Введение в ПД",
          "type": "зачет",
          "number": 3,
          "place": "Б-209",
          "whiteWeek": 17
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "day": "ВТ",
      "pars": [
        {
          "name": "Программирование в ЗР",
          "number": 2,
          "place": "Б-209",
          "type": "зачет",
          "whiteWeek": 17
        },
        {
          "name": "Физкультура и спорт",
          "type": "зачет",
          "number": 5,
          "whiteWeek": 17
        }
      ]
    }]}

# loop over each day and pars inside it
for day in json_data['days']:
    for par in day['pars']:

        # check if Alex and print
        if par['name'] == 'Alex':
            print(par['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this was already answered here: [multiple Json objects in one file extract by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907633/multiple-json-objects-in-one-file-extract-by-python).

Where u can see how to store multiple objects in a file:

```
[
{"ID":"12345","Timestamp":"20140101", "Usefulness":"Yes",
  "Code":[{"event1":"A","result":"1"},…]},
{"ID":"1A35B","Timestamp":"20140102", "Usefulness":"No",
  "Code":[{"event1":"B","result":"1"},…]},
{"ID":"AA356","Timestamp":"20140103", "Usefulness":"No",
  "Code":[{"event1":"B","result":"0"},…]},
...
]
```

And later on load them:

```
import json

with open('file.json') as json_file:

data = json.load(json_file)
```

Where `data` is a python list of dicts (as [bruno-desthuilliers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) pointed out):

```
data[index]["name"]
```

Comment: "Where data is an json object array" => nope, it's a Python list of dicts.

Comment: Thanks, I just guessed what it would be I dont use python.

Answer (score -1):

While I am not a python guy. If I had to do that in c++ 
I would create own parser for JSON file and create a Token tree with all it's property and then use that as your library.

```
or
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

```
or
```

invert bit time to get the JSON parser made by other fellows

```
or
```

see the same question at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791891/reading-and-writing-json-through-python/45791955)

Comment: I don't know if reinventing the wheel is a tradition amongst c++ programmers, but I'm pretty sure there are working, maintained C++ json parsers already...

Comment: And that's what i am talking about. You can get any prebuild parsers and head on to the documentation provided

Comment: "If I had to do that in c++ I would create own parser for JSON" ;-) (but I was mostly nitpicking you, sorry )

Comment: No problem. By the way the answer of @GuillemVs seems to be working even I hadn't tried

Comment: Yep, it _should_ be working - assuming he correctly guessed what the OP's data really look like of course...