# How to read Json data using python?

Tags: python, json, automation, robotframework

I have the response message below and code which I follow

result=  a["{\"msg\":\"result\",\"id\”:\”test\”,\”result\":{\"categories\":[\"<20M\",\"20M+\",\"50M+\",\"300M+\",\"1G\"],\"series\":[{\"name\":\"Fiber\",\"data\":[216,41,10393,37394,6016]}],\"totals\":{\"<20M\":216,\"20M+\":41,\"50M+\":10393,\"300M+\":37394,\"1G\":6016}}}"]

```
#Remove a
     sliceresult=result[1:]
    print('Result After slice: {}'.format(sliceresult))
    string_input = ''.join(str(s) for s in sliceresult)
    print(string_input)
    category = json.loads(string_input)['result']['categories']
    series = json.loads(string_input)['result']['series']
    total = json.loads(string_input)['result']['totals']
    print(category, series, total)
    Error Response was:
        category = json.loads(result[1:])['result']['categories']
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading and Writing JSON through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791891/reading-and-writing-json-through-python)

Comment: I can't able to get the categories values separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you to begin with:

```
 a = ["{\"msg\":\"result\",\"id\":\"test\",\"result\":{\"categories\":[\"<20M\",\"20M+\",\"50M+\",\"300M+\",\"1G\"],\"series\":[{\"name\":\"Fiber\",\"data\":[216,41,10393,37394,6016]}],\"totals\":{\"<20M\":216,\"20M+\":41,\"50M+\":10393,\"300M+\":37394,\"1G\":6016}}}"]

string_input = ''.join(str(s) for s in a)
print(string_input)

    category = json.loads(string_input)['result']['categories']
    series = json.loads(string_input)['result']['series']
    total = json.loads(string_input)['result']['totals']
    print(category, series, total)
```

Also be careful, your input string is not properly formatted.
it should be `"` not `”`

Comment: this one works fine but how should I remove '[ ]' square brackets in the response

Comment: then in your case it's not json , it's a list. I have modified my answers, that will definitely help.

Comment: # Removing a  from the string                                                                                      sliceresult=result[1:]
print('Result After slice: {}'.format(sliceresult))
string_input = ''.join(str(s) for s in sliceresult)
print(string_input)

category = json.loads(string_input)['result']['categories']
series = json.loads(string_input)['result']['series']
total = json.loads(string_input)['result']['totals']
print(category, series, total)

Comment: I followed this code and got an error was                                                                category = json.loads(string_input)['result']['categories']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I edited latest code, could u please review it because in my response 'a' also included

Comment: I can't review it and be helpful here, because if I try to replicate and add `a` next to`[]`, in python you will get unresolved reference for `a`. To help you have to tell me what is `a`?

Comment: in websocket response 'a' also included because a indicates active state